# Wrap divs in bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a container with few `<div>`s (border circle) and I want them to wrap when the resolution gets lower. The container has `class="col-md-8"`. It behaves fine but on smaller resolutions whole `container` escapes beyond background. Instead it should wrap every `<div>` and put it under the others. Here is a similar result, like the one I want to achive:
[image: image of responsive divs]

```css
#ct-skills{
  background: grey;
  height: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }

  #skills-circles{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .ct-circle{
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     }

     .circle{
       height: 150px;
       width: 150px;
       border: 5px solid black;
       border-radius: 50%;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-family: "Raleway";
       color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
      }
      
      span{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "Raleway";
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="ct-skills">
  <h3>Our skills</h3>
  <div class="col-md-8" id="skills-circles">
    <div class="ct-circle">
      <div class="circle">
        <span>10%</span>
      </div>
      <span>Marketing</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ct-circle">
      <div class="circle">
        <span>10%</span>
      </div>
      <span>Research</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ct-circle">
      <div class="circle">
        <span>10%</span>
      </div>
      <span>Management</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ct-circle">
      <div class="circle">
        <span>10%</span>
      </div>
      <span>Consultancy</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ct-circle">
      <div class="circle">
        <span>10%</span>
      </div>
      <span>Promotion</span>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: The bootstrap columns require to be placed inside `row` elements to function properly.

Comment: I tried this solution earlier and it didn't worked for me. Maybe becouse i applied flex properies and it overwriten the bootstrap original code. and therefore its not working

Comment: You can not expect things to still work as intended, when you make significant changes to how the bootstrap layouting mechanism works. Bootstrap v4 has flexbox support, but if you can only use v3, then I would recommend that you rather style this (that specific part of the site) yourself completely, and don’t use any of the bootstrap layout classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
#ct-skills{
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }

  #skills-circles{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
   }

   .ct-circle{
     min-height: 150px;
     min-width: 150px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: stretch;
     justify-content: center;
     margin: 20px;
     }

     .circle{
       min-height: 100%;
       min-width: 100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border: 5px solid black;
       border-radius: 50%;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-family: "Raleway";
       color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
      }

      span{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "Raleway";
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/zeo5amvn/

Comment: This is it! Great job! so can you explain what was major issiue? I see u added min-width and-heigh.

Comment: this is flexbox feature

Answer (score 2):

If i truly understand what you want you can only do this by a little change:

```
#skills-circles {
display: flex;
border: 1px solid yellow;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

}

And remove `width:100%;` from .ct-circle

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: I want #skills-circles to display inline. After adding flex wrap it displays like a column which is not the effect i want to achieve. Width property is there becouse i have a background image whitch i want to cover all width space.